# jQuery - Toggle an attribute

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle, attr

I have the following code

```
value.bind( function( to ) {
    $( '#header.alt.reveal' ).attr('style', 'background:transparent;', to );
```

It's placed in a function that adds the attribute when a checkbox is checked. However, I want to make this toggle so that when it is unchecked the attribute is removed. Can someone explain how I do this please

For a bit of context - this is the js file that controls real time changes in the wordpress customizer - the whole of this snippet looks like this:

```
// FRONT PAGE MENU TRANSPARENCY
wp.customize( 'front_page_menu_transaprency', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        $( '#header.alt.reveal' ).toggle.attr('style', 'background:transparent;', to );

    });
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of parameter `to`???

Comment: @A.Wolff just added a bit of context to the question, thanks

Comment: Thx for update but i'm afraid, i don't know wp :(

Comment: @SamSkirrow According the documentation of Jquery, there are only two parameters for the method `.attr()`. For what stays the third parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this. I'm just changing the background color to red when something is true.

```
$('#header.alt.reveal').css('background-color', function () {
  return to ? '#f00' : 'transparent';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for something as follows:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#header.alt.reveal').addClass('classname');
   }else{
       $('#header.alt.reveal').removeClass('classname');
   }
});
```

Comment: I was totally misunderstanding the question. You could make this a little less repetitive by doing: `$('#header.alt.reveal').toggleClass('classname', this.checked);`